# Cell range is shifting automatically in formula

Tags: excel, vba

In LONG SHORT tab L N and O column is linked from ALL DATA tab. When I run the macro to update the data in ALL DATA tab the range in long short tab is automatically shifted.

I need to lock the range.

Code by which ALL DATA tab is updating. After that range is shifting in LONG SHORT TAB:

[image: LONG SHORT]

```vb
Sub datacopy()
    Sheets("All Data").Activate
    'lastrow = Sheets("All Data").Range("C55555").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("All Data").Range("C4").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Resize(11).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
    Sheets("DERIVATIVES OI").Range("A2:O7").Copy
    Sheets("All Data").Range("c4:q9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("DASHBOARD").Activate
    
    MsgBox "DATA UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY !"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard Excel behavior. You are inserting data by a shift down and a paste action. So all your references to cells move with it, even if you lock it with the $.

One way to get around this is using the Indirect function:

```
= INDIRECT("'All Data'!D6")-INDIRECT("'All Data'!D17")
```

Comment: sir I tried this mothed but its not working.@Aldert

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer..

Comment: sir now getting this error. #REF!

Comment: Strange, for me this is working. Can you do a simple test like : = INDIRECT("All Data!D6")

Comment: SIR same error i found #REF!

Comment: I see the problem already, needs extra quotes, see answer. There is a space in your sheet name so in needs 'All Data'

Comment: thank you so much sir now this function is working properly.